# Can I connect to irc, icq, sip, etc services using WebSockets providing I have some sort implementation of those protocols in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I would like to connect to to irc, icq, sip, etc services using WebSockets. 
Assuming I have some sort implementation of those protocols in JavaScript ?
Is that possible? I don't seems to understand limitations of WebSockets comparing to regular sockets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't, at least not directly.

WebSockets allow real-time messaging between a browser and a WebSocket server, but they have their own layer 7 protocol for encapsulating those messages.

They *don't* provide access to a pure TCP (or UDP) socket over which you can implement existing protocols.

Comment: you can make a server-socket side with for e.g. PHP. The IRC RFC can be reproduced as is.

Comment: @Leandro and what about the client side?

Comment: client will use the served-translation.

Answer (score 8):

**Absolutely!**

The caveat is that you need something to bridge between the WebSocket transport protocol of the browser and the raw TCP socket of the existing service. For example, something like [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) (disclaimer: I created websockify). Another caveat is that websockify only supports TCP targets (WebSocket is TCP only right now so supporting UDP targets would be a little odd anyways).

The websockify project actually includes two proof of concept HTML/Javascript pages to communicate with IRC and telnet. If you are interested in leveraging websockify to build HTML/Javascript clients for some common TCP protocols, I might even pull them into the websockify repo as examples (assuming they are well coded and under an open source license.

An alternative to websockify is to integrate websocket server-side support directly into the servers you wish to communicate with. It's not all that difficult to add support. WebSocket has a very simple framing and while the handshake is compatible with HTTP servers it's actually much more restricted and simple and doesn't require a full HTTP parser. For example, libvncserver 0.9.9 now supports both regular VNC connections and VNC connections over WebSocket. This allows noVNC (which I also created) to connect directly to a libvncserver based VNC server without requiring websockify.

Comment: For this I need to install wbesockify on the server, right? What if I want to access an arbitrary IRC server?

Comment: You can run websockify on the client, on the server or on a completely different system. The browser just has to be able to open connections to websockify and websockify needs to be able to open connections to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Inspircd has an unofficial module you can install called `m_websockets`, to allow connection. A server that has the module installed and setup will allow you to connect to the server via webbsockets.

https://github.com/barosl/inspircd-m_websocket

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @kanaka's websockify, this project seems to do it:

> A HTML5 irc-client, made with websocket and websockify.
>
> [Has] support for autojoin, privmsg channel, topic, join, userlist, part, nick.

https://github.com/confact/dunirc

Answer (score 0):

Since 2021, there is a (draft) standard for IRC over WebSockets by the IRCv3 working group: https://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/websocket

Each IRC message is contained in a separate WebSocket message, instead of being delimited by CRLF. This is a similar approach to the other answers here and [UnrealIRCd's m_websocket](https://www.unrealircd.org/docs/WebSocket_support).

Libera.Chat and Snoonet are two networks that currently support IRCv3 websockets. Both are currently locked down to allow only specific [HTTP origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) to curb abuse potential.

Answer (score -1):

No, not with websockets, but you can with http.

[Samy Kamkar gave a black hat talk about this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5xRRF5GfQs&feature=youtu.be&t=30m20s)